# How to hide protected operating system files in the VSCode workspace?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, visual-studio-code

Although I have ticked "Hide protected operating system files" from Windows 10 file explorer options, I  can still see files like `desktop.ini` and other random files with long names.

I've tried toggling hidden items from file explorer but that doesn't do anything.

Is there a way to hide these from VSCode?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any setting for that.

If you are looking for hiding specific files or extensions, this is possible
by modifying the configuration.

In the default setting, VSCode will exclude the following files in the display list:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true
}
```

You may add to the list any other files or extensions that you wish hidden.

Answer (score 0):

By default they are not shown if vscode is using Common Dialogs. A program has to explicitly ask for hidden or system files to be shown. However the OpenFileDialog never shows protected system files.

> OFN_FORCESHOWHIDDEN Windows 2000/XP: Forces the showing of system and
> hidden files, thus overriding the user setting to show or not show
> hidden files. However, a file that is marked both system and hidden is
> not shown.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea